# How to use a join on two statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a statement that counts how many records that have `attr3 = 1`.

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM ((select attr3 from table1) union all
      (select attr3 from table2)
     ) t
WHERE attr3 = '1';
```

Now I need to have another statement that does the same thing but counts how many records that have `attr3 = 2`.

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
    FROM ((select attr3 from table1) union all
          (select attr3 from table2)
         ) t2
    WHERE attr3 = '2';
```

Ideally the data will display in this format

```
Dept         count(*)
attr3 = 1          4
attr3 = 2          6
```

This method works if I do the statements separately, I just simply want to join them together. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best suggestion, but if I'm understand you correctly, you can maybe wrap the two in subqueries, and then cartesian product them, and then select only the 1s and the 2s

Comment: Use the `OR` operator - `WHERE attr3 = '1' OR attr3 = '2'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` and `WHERE attr3 in()` should suffice.

```
SELECT Z.attr3 as Dept, count(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT attr3 FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT attr3 FROM table2) Z
WHERE attr3 in ('1','2')
GROUP BY Z.attr3
```

Since attr3 defines the groups you want to count by, simply group by it and limit the results to your 1,2 after the union via a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The group by will do the job.

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM ((select attr3 from table1) union all
      (select attr3 from table2)
     ) t2
WHERE attr3 = '2'
group by dept;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Close, but how would this return record for attr3 for group 1?  Seems like this would only return attr3 for group 2.